# Shape of Limiting Polygon

Tags: geometry, curves, recursion

Start with an equilateral triangle with unit area. Trisect each of the sides and then cut-off the corners. In this case, we get a regular hexagon. Next, trisect each of the sides of the hexagon and cut-off the corners. This will give a dodecagon, but *not a regular one*.

Continue this process ad infinitum.

What is the **shape** of the limiting "polygon"?

I know the polygon must be continuous but isn't differenciable, and that it has symmetry $S_3$. I also know the area ($4/7$). It's not a circle, constant diameter shape, or a finite collection of beizier curves. It is convex.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51008/limit-of-a-sequence-of-polygons and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/438022/de-rhams-trisection-method-english

Comment: Gregory and Qu proved that the limit is not smooth in this case. Smoothness of the limit requires cutting at strictly less than $1/3$. See their paper [Nonuniform corner cutting](https://doi.org/10.1016/0167-8396(96)00008-8) (p 771).

Comment: but the limit has a continuous derivative?

Comment: It seems that the centers of the sides of the triangle are remaining untouched and such each side center that is result of the cuts. It seems that you could get close to a circle as much as you want.

Comment: No, the area doesn't match one of a circle's.